# Как сделать множественную замену во множестве файлов?

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, visual-studio-code, sublime-text

Sublime Text имеет плагин RegReplace для множественной замены в одном (открытом) файле. Но нужна возможность производить аналогичную замену сразу во многих файлах. Она есть? Может, в других редакторах?

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться powershell для windows или bash для linux

Answer (score 1):

В рабочей области нажимаете по нужной папке ПКМ, выбираете "Найти в папке..." ("Find in the folder...", сочетание клавиш <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего переключится вкладка на "Поиск", выглядеть он будет так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле "Поиск" вписываете нужное значение по которому будет проводиться поиск (поддерживает опции: учитывать регистр, слово целиком, регулярные выражения).
В поле "Заменить" значение на которое заменить. Справа от этого поля (за его пределами), отображается кнопка "Заменить всё", используйте её для запуска замены.

Выше описана замена в тексте на активной вкладке редактора, для использования замены в нескольких файлах, используются следующие два поля "Включаемые файлы" ("Included files") и "Исключаемые файлы" ("Excluded files").

В данных полях можно использовать конструкции:
`*.ts` - замена выполнится во всех файлах с расширением файла `.js`;
`src/**/include` - выполнится во всех директориях `/include`, что содержатся в `/src`;
Так же вы можете перечислить файлы и комбинации через запятую `*.ts, /src/**/include, index.html`.

Comment: Вы описали поиск и замену какого-то одного выражения на другое во множестве файлов, а нужно, чтобы во множестве файлов производилась замена целого списка одних выражений на список других.